# How to find the unknown values of a natural log function.

Tags: functions

[image]

I was able to do (a) and (b), but couldn't find the answer for (c). I thought I would be able to find them by creating a simultaneous equation, and one of the equations I found is 4a+b=1, by using the graph. Can someone find what the other equation would be?

Answer (score 1):

For the other equation, note that the singularity -- the point where the function goes to negative infinity -- is at $x = 1$. The $\log$ function goes to negative infinity when its argument goes to zero. Thus, $a \times 1 + b = 0$ is the other equation.